# Solutions to a Linear system over an $arbitrary$ field

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, systems-of-equations

It is often stated in linear algebra classe that in a $m\times n$ linear system $Ax=b$ over R, the solution set is either:

- **empty**
- **exactly one element**
- **infinitely many element**

And the proof for that goes:

> suppose $u, v$ distinct solution, then $\forall \lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{R}\ \ s.t.\ \ \lambda+\mu=1: \lambda u+\mu v$ is a solution too, yielding infinitely many

This however is specific to $\mathbb{R}$ and I am trying to find hypotheses have to hold on an arbitrary field, so that the solution set behaves in the same way (i.e. have either no, one, or infinitely many sols.).

It is obvious it can't be true for finite fields. But only admitting the field has to be infinite doesn't intuitively seem to be enough.

Would there then be infinite pairs $\mu, \lambda$ adding up to 1? Do we need to have an ordering relation? Any help or clue would be appreciated.

Comment: Very strange to downvote such a question. The downvoter should take the time to expose his motivations for downvoting.

Comment: For the conclusion "infinitely many", you need an infinite field. For example, if your field is $\mathbb F_2$, then you could easily have exactly $2$ solutions, or $4$ solutions, or $8$ solutions, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $Ax_1=Ax_2=b,$ then $A(x_1+t(x_2-x_1))=b$ for any $t$ in your field. If $x_1\neq x_2,$ this gives a set $x(t)=x_1+t(x_2-x_1)=(1-t)x_1+tx_2$ solutions.

It is pretty easy to show that $x(t)\neq x(t')$ when $t\neq t'.$

So if the field is infinite, and there is more than one solution, there are infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 1):

*...But only admitting the field has to be infinite doesn't intuitively seem to be enough...*

Your intuition is not correct. If the system $Ax=b$ has more than a single solution, then the kernel $\ker A$ of $A$ is a linear subspace having a dimension greater or equal to one. Notice that the cardinal of a linear subspace of a linear space of dimension greater or equal to one is at least equal to the cardinal of its field. And finally, the cardinal of the solutions of $Ax=b$ is the one of $\ker A$ if a solution exists.

Hence if the solutions set has more than one element, it is infinite if the cardinal of the field is infinite.